# Find m smallest elements in an array of size n where m = n/2

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sorting, selection-problem

So we have an unsorted array, we need to find the first $m$ elements in ascending order (or $m$ smallest elements) where $m = \mathrm{array.size}/2$ (or $n/2$). How would we do this in linear $O(n)$ time.

What I was thinking of doing was use the SELECT algorithm to find the kth smallest element until $k = m$, but this way the complexity would be $n/2 \cdot O(n) = O(n^2)$.

Comment: You want to find the $m$ smallest numbers, *and* they have to be sorted? If yes, it is not possible to do so because it will give a $O(n)$ solution to sort the entire array and this violates the fact that comparison-based algorithm must sort in $\Omega(\log n)$

Comment: @ChristopherBoo I think that “in ascending order” might explain what we mean by “first $m$ elements”.

Answer (score 2):

Find the median in $O(n)$ time. Then go over the array and take out all elements smaller than the median.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a min heap ($O(n)$) and then perform extract min m times. ($O(mlogn)$). Time complexity will be $O(n) + O(nlogn)$.

Comment: While this does not answer *How would we [find the $m$ smallest elements] in linear $O(n)$ time*, it *does* present *how to find the first $m$ elements in ascending order*.